# Using "for" to align paired end sequences

Tags: linux, terminal, alignment

I have a folder with many paired end files (`1.1.fq 1.2.fq 2.1.fq 2.2.fq ...`) I want to use the "for" to do the aligment for each pair (`*.1fq *2.fq`) and generate 2 outputs `*.stats.txt` and `*.sam`.
I wrote the following command:

```
for x in *.fq ; do 
    ~/Pedro_Dias/Mamão/Single_end/novocraft/novoalign -d cpapaya.novoIndex -f demultiplex-fq/$x *.1.fq demultiplex-fq/$x *.2.fq -x 3 -H -a -o SAM 2> demultiplex-sam/$x *.stats.txt > demultiplex-sam/$x *.sam; 
done
```

The code return the error:

```
demultiplex-sam/demultiplex-fq/98.1.fq*.stats.txt:No file or directory
```

P.s. My files were in `demultiplex-fq` folder and the output must go to the `demultiplex-sam` folder. I'm working in a folder that contains the `demultiplex-fq` `demultiplex-sam` folders.

Answer (score 0):

You should just loop over one file in the pairs. Then replace `.1.fq` with `.2.fq` to get the other file in that pair.

The wildcards need to include the directory name, and then you have to replace the directory when generating the output filenames.

```
for x in demultiplex-fq/*.1.fq
do
    y=${x/.1.fq/.2.fq}
    stats=${x/demultiplex-fq/demultiplex/sam}.stats.txt
    sam=${x/demultiplex-fq/demultiplex/sam}.sam
    ~/Pedro_Dias/Mamão/Single_end/novocraft/novoalign -d cpapaya.novoIndex -f "$x" "$y" -x 3 -H -a -o SAM 2> "$stats" > "$sam"
```

You don't use wildcards in the command, you just use the `$x` and `$y` variables.

Comment: It generates just two files *1.fq.sam and *1.fq.stats.txt

Comment: That will only happen if there are no `*.1.fq` files in the current folder.

Comment: I see, the problem is that the input files are in a subdirectory, the wildcard needs to specify the directory.

Comment: I try other code and works...thanks so much... I will out the new code at the answers

Answer (score 0):

I used that code and works:

```
for x in $( ls -1 dem*/*.fq | rev | cut -d . -f 3- | rev | sort -u ) ; do    ~/Pedro_Dias/Mamão/Single_end/novocraft/novoalign -d cpapaya.novoIndex -f $x.1.fq $x.2.fq -x 3 -H -a -o SAM 2> ./bams/$(echo $x | tr / _).stats.txtx > ./bams/$(echo $x | tr / _).sam; done
```